# Array of String values, not an array of object Strings

Tags: php

Basically I am calling an API to get an array of URLs for an image.

I start off by doing this

```
$mainResponse = array(
      "result" => array(
      ),
      "ack" => "success"
 );
```

I will then make my call and add the image URLs like this:

```
foreach($resp->Item as $item) {
  $picture = $item->PictureURL;
  array_push($mainResponse['result'], $picture);
}
```

Finally, I will echo this out to me.

```
 echo json_encode($mainResponse);
```

The problem I am facing is that my response is

```
{"result":[{"0":"IMAGE_URL","1":"IMAGE_URL"}],"ack":"success"}
```

Where I would want it to be like....

```
{"result":["IMAGE_URL","IMAGE_URL"],"ack":"success"}
```

Where did I go wrong in my PHP code?

Comment: can you print_r($resp->Item); please?

Comment: Some codes are missed here. You can't convert array to object implicitly. But `PictureURL` property can be array of strings. Then you'll get this output.

Comment: ahhh @u_mulder you are right. i forgot to add that into there, but I did figure out the issue. If I do strval($pic) ill get the string value and not a set of objects.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like $picture is a associative array, change the foreach loop with this:

```php
foreach($resp->Item->PictureURL as $item) {
 foreach($item as $_item){
  array_push($mainResponse['result'],$_item);}
}
```

Comment: This is not dynamic. Not a good answer at all. Not always will there be 2 pictures. There may be 1, 2, 3... n or even 0.

Comment: @soldfor check now

Answer (score 1):

For some reason this API returns an object instead of an array.
You can just do:

```
foreach ($resp->Item as $item) {
    $picture = $item->PictureURL;
    array_merge($mainResponse['result'], (array)$picture);
}
```

You can use `array_push` if you want every item to have separate pictures.